# How do I configure SSHd to require 2 (or more) passwords to log in

Tags: linux, debian, sshd

I'm asking because I want to setup a server that cannot be administered by any single admin, not without the permission (and oversight) of one other authorized admin (there can be many). Since there can be more than 2 authorized admins the simple trick to divide the passwords into two halves would not work here.

The workflow I have in mind is something like this:

- You connect to the server via SSH.
- You are prompted for a valid admin password (you know only one).
- You are prompted for a second valid admin password (ask your colleague very nicely to input his password).
- You are logged in and can now do the work you are supposed to do, preferably under the supervision of your fellow admin.
- You log out when finished (obviously).

Now I realize there are a number of caveats to this approach:

1. Once logged in you are root and can install whatever backdoor you want or you can disable to second password prompt. If you are prepared it should probably be easy to fool the other admin by running some seemingly innocent script that you have prepared before-hand.
2. If you are connecting from your own workstation you could also install a key-logger to learn the other admins password.
3. The changing of your own admin password would probably require 2 people, which would be annoying.
4. More?

That said, I do think there are scenarios where this kind of setup would be useful.

Does a solution for this already exist? Because that would be great!

Comment: What are you concerned with happening if an admin could get to root by themselves?

Comment: you could let the first user `sudo` only if there is another user in the admin group logged in

Comment: Related: [How to configure pam to use with two different passwords?](http://superuser.com/q/896158/150988)

Comment: @Bratchley Well, say you have an email server that you administer and you do not want the administrators to read the emails that are stored there, but you still need a way to maintain the machine. If 2 administrators are required they can both ensure that the other does not look at whatever sensitive files are stored there.

Comment: It's just an idea, I know its not perfect...

Comment: Another thing to consider is that now two admins are required to do anything. One to do the work and another one to I guess watch. You might be better off trusting your admin, doing some audit logging, and doing some after-the-fact analytics.

Comment: Ultimately, you need to be able to trust the admins. There are a million different ways to get around this, including just two admins getting together and deciding to read other people's emails. Admins are going to have access to sensitive data so if you can't trust them then they probably shouldn't be your admins.

Comment: I second @Bratchley in this. The question itself is interesting but this system is not going to be bulletproof (as already pointed out in the OP) so at the end of the day you need to find admins who are trustworthy and relying on that rather than strict control. Obviously you can audit logs, as Bratchley suggests but that's a tad different.

Comment: The problem is not to find trustworthy admins (since it's me, my data and my machine, and I do actually trust me). The problem is how do I convince others that I am trustworthy... The question is pureley academic since I don't in reality have anyone to convince, like I said it's just my own data... but still I would like to know if and how it can be done (from a purely technical perspective).